# How to install Docker CE on RHEL 7.2, since we are doing a poc we dont want to pay for EE

Tags: docker, rhel7

We are having RHEL 7.2, native docker is not available in the OS. So for installing Docker CE, we have to install docker using CentOS repo (read from blogs). Is this the only option available to install docker on RHEL?

Answer (score 1):

Docker is also available via the `rhel-7-server-extras-rpms` repository, assuming you have the correct subscription attached to your RHEL 7.2 installation.

You can enable the repository with this command:

```
$ sudo subscription-manager repos --enable rhel-7-server-extras-rpms
```

After that, you should see docker available to you.